# Error in C++ list::sort

Tags: c++, list, stl

Getting a bunch of errors and they are very cryptic.

Here's all the relevant code:

```
// list::sort
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include "main.h"

using namespace std;

struct texture
{
    int texture;
    int ref;
};

bool compare_nocase (texture first, texture second)
{
    if(first.texture < second.texture)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

int main ()
{
  list<texture> mylist;
  list<texture>::iterator it;

  texture moose;
  moose.ref = 3;
  moose.texture = 6;

  texture moose2;
  moose2.ref = 1;
  moose2.texture = 3;

  texture moose3;
  moose3.ref = 2;
  moose3.texture = 14;

  mylist.push_back (moose);
  mylist.push_back (moose2);
  mylist.push_back (moose3);

  cout << "before sort mylist contains:";
  for (it=mylist.begin(); it!=mylist.end(); ++it)
      cout << it->texture << endl;
  cout << endl;


  mylist.sort(compare_nocase);

  cout << "after sort mylist contains:";
  for (it=mylist.begin(); it!=mylist.end(); ++it)
    cout << it->texture << endl;
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I am just testing out the STL sort function but I get the errors:

```
c:\users\spaniel\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\list\list\main.cpp(12): error C2380: type(s) preceding 'texture' (constructor with return type, or illegal redefinition of current class-name?)
1>c:\users\spaniel\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\list\list\main.cpp(18): error C2274: 'function-style cast' : illegal as right side of '.' operator
1>c:\users\spaniel\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\list\list\main.cpp(18): error C2274: 'function-style cast' : illegal as right side of '.' operator
1>c:\users\spaniel\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\list\list\main.cpp(35): error C2274: 'function-style cast' : illegal as right side of '.' operator
1>c:\users\spaniel\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\list\list\main.cpp(39): error C2274: 'function-style cast' : illegal as right side of '.' operator
1>c:\users\spaniel\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\list\list\main.cpp(43): error C2274: 'function-style cast' : illegal as right side of '.' operator
1>c:\users\spaniel\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\list\list\main.cpp(51): error C2273: 'function-style cast' : illegal as right side of '->' operator
1>c:\users\spaniel\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\list\list\main.cpp(59): error C2273: 'function-style cast' : illegal as right side of '->' operator
```

Answer (score 6):

You have a `struct` member `texture` with the same name as the `struct` itself.

Apparently VS 2010 doesn't like this, although GCC 4.1.2 is fine.  I'm not sure which is correct...

Comment: Yep, gcc is really OK with that and I don't see a reason, this to be wrong :?

Comment: There is a good reason for it to be wrong. It makes references to `texture` inside the member functions of the struct highly ambiguous and confusing. This is especially a problem if whatever type `texture` is defines `operator ()`. Then you can't even tell if you're trying to construct a new `texture` or using the function call operator on the `texture` member.

Comment: @Omnifarious: I agree.  But that said, there are plenty of places where C++ has opportunity to be confusing and ambiguous (to a human reader).  The question is, which compiler is doing the right thing here?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Of course, just because there's a really good reason for it to be wrong doesn't mean it is. *sigh* Welcome to C++. I love the language, but... *deeper sigh* What's really amusing is that you wrote what you wrote at the same time I was writing this.

Comment: Interestingly gcc is right, even though I thought it the other way around. The relevant bits of the standard are: 9.2/13, that enumerates which members must not have the same name as the class (data members are not present in the list), and 9.2/13a that requires data members not to share the name of the class *if there is a user defined constructor*.

Comment: @David: If that's the case, then this is more than just a compiler bug on MS's part.  Even their interpretation of the standard is incorrect; see the code example on their help page for this error (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bcktt82(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, @David: This is really quite bizarre, and I created a StackOverflow question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829744/why-does-this-program-call-operator-instead-of-the-constructor

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you cannot do like this:

```
struct texture
{
        v name is conflicted with struct name
    int texture;
    int ref;
};
```