# Why does this program call operator () instead of the constructor?

Tags: c++

Here is a program that compiles without warning on e.g. GNU C++:

```
$ g++ -o t -Wall -pedantic -Wshadow t.cpp

$ ./t.exe
Calling barney::barney()
Calling foo::operator()()
Calling barney::barney()
```

But it completely fails to compile on MSVC++:

```
$ cl /EHsc t.cpp
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.30729.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

t.cpp
t.cpp(17) : error C2380: type(s) preceding 'fred' (constructor with return type, or illegal redefinition of current class-name?)
t.cpp(17) : error C2208: 'fred' : no members defined using this type
```

**What's more, when it does compile, the output is not what I'd expect. Can someone shed some light on what would be the required standard behaviour for this code**?

Here it is:

```
#include <iostream>

using ::std::cerr;

struct fred;

struct foo {
   inline fred operator ()();
};

struct barney {
   barney() : v_(0) { cerr << "Calling barney::barney()\n"; }
   int v_;
};

struct fred : public barney {
   foo fred;
   int joe;
   struct fred memfunc() { return fred(); }
};

inline fred foo::operator ()()
{
   cerr << "Calling foo::operator()()\n"; return fred();
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
   fred f;
   f.memfunc();
   return 0;
}
```

It outputs this:

```
Calling barney::barney()
Calling foo::operator()()
Calling barney::barney()
```

But I would expect this:

```
Calling barney::barney()
Calling barney::barney()
```

Why do I get the output I do? Is this standard behavior? If it is, why, which sections of the standard are relevant?

In addition to the accepted answer, [David Rodriguez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36565/david-rodriguez-dribeas) gave an [excellent answer detailing where it says in the standard that I'm allowed to declare the member named `fred` of `struct fred`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829744/why-does-this-program-call-operator-instead-of-the-constructor/5830023#5830023).

Comment: Don't use same names for variables and classes and your life will become easier. Common convention is to name classes with upper-case.
In your code `fred` is both a class name and a member name. Use different names and you won't have to think what compiler will choose.

Comment: Obviously this is standard behaviour. Why do you want to discuss it? Maybe we can discuss next time: why is `a + b * c` evaluated as `a + (b*c)`, not `(a+b) * c`? Same situation, really

Comment: @sehe: But why does it pick the member variable name over the type name? It seems really ambiguous to me, like it should generate an error.

Comment: @sehe, it may be obvious to you, but not to the OP, hence the question...

Comment: compiler should give error/warning for such usage.

Comment: I'm not discussing whether it should be obvious beforehand. Once the compiler emits the code, it quickly _becomes rather obvious_. (If this is a case of _the compiler took my biscuit_, well, blahhhh. If there something else (like: `compiler X says something else`), that _would_ be more off a substance)

Comment: @iammilind, @sehe: It so happens that Visual Studio generates an error, but the error it gives is exemplary of a compiler bug, and a bug in Microsoft's interpretation of the standard. But I agree, it should warrant a warning even though it isn't an error. Basically you are only allowed to have a member of the same name as your class/struct if your class/struct has no user-defined constructors.

Comment: @Omnifarioius: I updated the question to reflect the true dilemma (I think). Also, [you can always _answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq)_

Comment: @sehe: I know I can answer my own question. :-) I just like giving out puzzles, and this was quite an interesting interaction between a little known part of the standard and name lookup rules. And thank you for updating the question. I don't have Visual C++ around myself. I knew it would fail from a different question I saw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because in the `fred` structure you have a member `fred` (of type `foo`) which shadows the definition of `struct fred`. When you then do:

```
return fred();
```

... the `fred` refers to the object of type `foo` rather than the `fred` struct type, and so the `foo` () operator is called.

Notice that the name "fred" refers to two different things - the member, of type foo, and the `fred` struct type. The compiler must choose one or the other, and it does so according to the rules defined in section 3.4 ("Name Lookup") of the C++ standard.

You can force `fred` to refer to the type using a namespace qualification:

```
return ::fred();
```

Comment: How do I return an instance of a default constructed `fred` then and avoid calling `foo::operator()()`?

Comment: Untested, but I think `return ::fred();` might do the trick. Of course the best answer is not to have a member whose name matches that of the enclosing type.

Comment: @Omnifarious, qualify it with a namespace, in this case the default - i.e. `::fred()`

Comment: @davmac: It does! Do you happen to know the relevant sections the standard that cause this weird behavior?

Comment: 3.4 Name Lookup. And the behavior isn't really weird - the name "fred" refers to two things, the compiler has to pick one, and it does so by a defined set of rules...

Comment: @davmac: That makes sense. Would you like to edit your answer to include the stuff in the comments?

Answer (score 6):

On the *it should generate an error* part of the question. Not according to the standard:

9.2 [class.mem]/13

> If T is the name of a class, then each of the following shall have a name different from T:

- every static data member of class T;
- every member function of class T [Note: this restriction does not apply to constructors, which do not have names (12.1) ] ;
- every member of class T that is itself a type;
- every enumerator of every member of class T that is an enumerated type; and
- every member of every anonymous union that is a member of class T.

9.2 [class.mem]/13a

> In addition, if class T has a user-declared constructor (12.1), every nonstatic data member of class T shall have a name different from T.

As to why does it find the member rather than the variable, that is pretty much consistent with how the identifiers are handled in C++, where there are two identifier spaces, one for user defined types and another for the rest of the elements (including typedefs):

```
struct test {};
void test() {}
// or (but not both)
// int test;
```

With those two definitions, `test` refers to the function (or variable), and `struct test` to the user defined type. This is the particular corner case where the use of `typedef` when declaring an `struct` in C makes a difference in C++, as it will inject the name in the common identifier space:

```
typedef struct test {} test; // now "test" is in both spaces
// void test() {}            // error: redefinition of "test"
```

Comment: @Omnifarious: That is what happens when the answer does not come in the first few minutes :)

Answer (score 3):

When you call `f.memfunc`, the call to `fred()` will resolve to the member named `fred` of type `foo`. Declaring `memfunc` as returning `struct fred` won't help you anything, since you cannot do polymorphism on return values in C++.

To make the `fred()` call resolve to the constructor of `struct fred`, qualify the call with a namespace (`::fred()`).

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you are calling the `operator()` on the member `fred`. Either change the name of the member, or use `::fred()` to refer to the struct `fred` in the global scope.